# AD B2C - How to set up custom email verification in Password Reset flow

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I have a requirement of customizing the email sent to the user, from AD B2C, when she/he resets the password.

I followed this documentation to set up the self-service password reset flow, and it works fine:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-password-reset-policy?pivots=b2c-custom-policy

To provide a branded email for the password reset, I'm following this code, since it looks like that the only other option is to use Display Controls, which are currently in public preview (so I cannot use them in production):
https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/custom-email-verifcation

The readme clearly states that it can be used also for the password reset, but the code only provides an example for the sign in email verification.

I tried to add the `verificationCode` `OutputClaim` in various `TechnicalProfiles`, but I'm unable to visualize the custom `verificationCode` textbox that is needed by the provided javascript code.

I'm thinking that maybe I should use a specific ContentDefinition, but I'm really struggling to find the correct way to update the custom policy xml.

**Update** to clarify: In the sign up example, the verification code is added to the `LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonEmail` `TechnicalProfile`:

```xml
<ClaimsProvider>
        <DisplayName>Local Account</DisplayName>
        <TechnicalProfiles>
          <TechnicalProfile Id="LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonEmail">
              <DisplayName>Email signup</DisplayName>
              <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>
              <Metadata>
                <!-- Demo: Disable the email verification-->
                <Item Key="EnforceEmailVerification">False</Item>
              </Metadata>
              <OutputClaims>
                <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId"/>
                <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="Verified.Email" Required="true"/>
                
                <!--Demo: Add the verification code claim type-->
                <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="verificationCode" Required="true"/>
```

Since I'm working on the password reset (orchestrated by the following `SubJourney`), we can see that it references the `LocalAccountDiscoveryUsingEmailAddress` `TechnicalProfile` in the first step:

```xml
    <SubJourney Id="PasswordReset" Type="Call">
          <OrchestrationSteps>
            <!--Sample: Validate user's email address. Run this step only when user resets the password-->
            <OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="ClaimsExchange">
              <ClaimsExchanges>
                <ClaimsExchange Id="PasswordResetUsingEmailAddressExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="LocalAccountDiscoveryUsingEmailAddress" />
              </ClaimsExchanges>
            </OrchestrationStep>
    
            <!--Sample: Collect and persist a new password. Run this step only when user resets the password-->
            <OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="ClaimsExchange">
              <ClaimsExchanges>
                <ClaimsExchange Id="NewCredentials" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="LocalAccountWritePasswordUsingObjectId" />
              </ClaimsExchanges>
            </OrchestrationStep>
          </OrchestrationSteps>
        </SubJourney>
```

Therefore, I added `verificationCode` to the `LocalAccountDiscoveryUsingEmailAddress` `TechnicalProfile`:

```xml
    <!-- This technical profile forces the user to verify the email address that they provide on the UI. Only after email is verified, the user account is
    read from the directory. -->
    <TechnicalProfile Id="LocalAccountDiscoveryUsingEmailAddress">
      <DisplayName>Reset password using email address</DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
      <Metadata>
        <Item Key="IpAddressClaimReferenceId">IpAddress</Item>
        <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.localaccountpasswordreset</Item>
        <Item Key="UserMessageIfClaimsTransformationBooleanValueIsNotEqual">Your account has been locked. Contact your support person to unlock it, then try again.</Item>
      </Metadata>
      <CryptographicKeys>
        <Key Id="issuer_secret" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_TokenSigningKeyContainer" />
      </CryptographicKeys>
      <IncludeInSso>false</IncludeInSso>
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="verificationCode" Required="true"/>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="Verified.Email" Required="true" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="userPrincipalName" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" />
      </OutputClaims>
      <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
        <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="REST-EmailVerification"/>
        <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingEmailAddress" />
      </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
    </TechnicalProfile>
```

But the related `TextBox` is not rendered in the page.

**Update 2**: I found out why the text box is not rendered. It's related to the used `ContentDefinition`. By using the `api.selfasserted.profileupdate` content definition despite the `api.localaccountpasswordreset` one, the field is displayed. Now I'm still working on it.

**Update 3**: I was able to make it work using the `api.selfasserted.profileupdate`content definition. I'll post the complete solution as soon as I finish the integration with the validation APIs.

Comment: Im just wondering if you ever figured this out? We are currently using the standard password reset email, and while its getting the job done, it would be nice to give it some customization. I don't need a fully custom email, just modify the template some.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to use the `api.selfasserted.profileupdate` content definition (instead of `api.localaccountpasswordreset`) for the `LocalAccountDiscoveryUsingEmailAddress` technical profile.

```xml
        <TechnicalProfile Id="LocalAccountDiscoveryUsingEmailAddress">
          <DisplayName>Reset password using email address</DisplayName>
          <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="IpAddressClaimReferenceId">IpAddress</Item>
            <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.selfasserted.profileupdate</Item>
            <Item Key="UserMessageIfClaimsTransformationBooleanValueIsNotEqual">Your account has been locked. Contact your support person to unlock it, then try again.</Item>
            <Item Key="EnforceEmailVerification">false</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <CryptographicKeys>
            <Key Id="issuer_secret" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_TokenSigningKeyContainer" />
          </CryptographicKeys>
          <IncludeInSso>false</IncludeInSso>
          <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="Verified.Email" Required="true" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="verificationCode" Required="true" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="userPrincipalName" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" />
          </OutputClaims>
          <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
            <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="REST-EmailVerification" />
            <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingEmailAddress" />
          </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
        </TechnicalProfile>
```

It looks mostly as a workaround, but it's the only option not to use the preview features of the display controls.

To further protect the validation, there is an API-side check in the REST-EmailVerification validation technical profile, that re-checks the code previously validated client-side:

```xml
          <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
            <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="REST-EmailVerification" />
            <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingEmailAddress" />
          </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
```

Additionally I'm currently adding a captcha to avoid abuses of the sending logics.

As soon as the display controls will be generally available, I'll reccomend my client to use them.

The reason why it didn't work with the password-reset-specific content definition, is that it doesn't support other custom fields:
https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/azure/active-directory-b2c/contentdefinitions
[image]

Comment: It's interesting that I got downvoted for actually answering the question. I clearly stated that - i quote myself from the first question - "the only other option is to use **Display Controls**, which **are currently in public preview** (**so I cannot use them in production**)".

i.e. I literally cannot use preview features in the production environment for company policies, so this was the only way to make it work -- and it's working as expected.

Comment: McBodge- As per your initial question "I have a requirement of customizing the email sent to the user" but where is your custom email UI code?

Answer (score 1):

Swap `verified.email` output claim with the reference to your displayControl in the technical profile for password reset, which is `LocalAccountDiscoveryUsingEmailAddress`.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-email-sendgrid#make-a-reference-to-the-displaycontrol

Its essentially the exact same steps, except you make the "make a reference" change to the `LocalAccountDiscoveryUsingEmailAddress` technical profile to show the display control on this specific page, which is referenced in Step 1 of the password reset journey to collect and verify the users email.

```xml
        <TechnicalProfile Id="LocalAccountDiscoveryUsingEmailAddress">
          <DisplayName>Reset password using email address</DisplayName>
          <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="IpAddressClaimReferenceId">IpAddress</Item>
            <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.localaccountpasswordreset</Item>
            <Item Key="UserMessageIfClaimsTransformationBooleanValueIsNotEqual">Your account has been locked. Contact your support person to unlock it, then try again.</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <CryptographicKeys>
            <Key Id="issuer_secret" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_TokenSigningKeyContainer" />
          </CryptographicKeys>
          <IncludeInSso>false</IncludeInSso>
          <DisplayClaims>
            <DisplayClaim DisplayControlReferenceId="emailVerificationControl" />
          </DisplayClaims>
          <OutputClaims>
            <!--<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="Verified.Email" Required="true" />-->
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="userPrincipalName" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" />
```

And if you want a different email template for password reset compared to Sign Up, recreate a new displayControl and reference a different template.

Comment: Hi Jas, thank you for your answer, but it's not applicable to my scenario: I'm, using the javascript fashion of managing the verificationCode, since DisplayControls are currently in Public Preview and I shouldn't use them in production:
https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/custom-email-verifcation

It says that "Custom email verification solution allows you to send your own custom email verification during sign-up or *password reset* user journey."
Am I forced to use display controls with the embedded password reset flow?

Comment: fyi I updated the first post to clarify what I was trying to do.

Comment: We would highly recommend our display control public preview over the JavaScript sample. That sample has known vulnerabilities (as we stated) since it’s driven by the client. And yes, if you really want to use that old sample, you need to target the specific content definition for the password reset page technical profile.